# How does Saudi Arabia prepare for when they run out of oil?

Tags: economy, saudi-arabia

I've thought of it many times, actually an "ally" due to the petro dollar, what programs has Saudi Arabia implemented to prepare for a transition to a post-oil world economy?

Comment: Hi and welcome this is an interesting topic, but we want to minimize opinion here, as mentioned in our [tour]. I took the liberty of a slight modification with that in mind.

Comment: sure; the article explains that the sovereign funds are there to make strategic investments for the future prosperity or 'thriving' of SA, for example higher education and so on; there's a paucity of that in SA as they just now buy in the expertise from Egypt and elsewhere.

Comment: what happened to my earlier comment which linked the article - I didn't delete it! I'd have asked this in Meta, but I can't seem to find the link for it.

Comment: here is the original [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_Investment_Fund_of_Saudi_Arabia)

Answer (score 5):

The crown prince has laid out a variety of diversification measures in something called [Vision 2030](http://vision2030.gov.sa/sites/default/files/NTP_En.pdf)

Major parts of this include:

Selling off 5% of ARAMCO to be traded publicly (the state's national oil company, often cited as the most valuable company in the world) in part to create a massive [sovereign wealth fund](https://www.theguardian.com/business/2016/apr/01/saudi-arabia-plans-to-sell-state-oil-assets-to-create-2tn-wealth-fund).

Creating a [megacity in the middle of the desert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neom) to be designated as a special economic zone for economic cooperation with Jordan and Egypt

[Socially modernizing](http://www.cnn.com/2017/10/25/opinions/can-bin-salman-really-change-saudi-opinion-ian-black/index.html) the country (to an extent) and starting a [green card system](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2016/apr/25/saudi-arabia-approves-ambitious-plan-to-move-economy-beyond-oil) to attract foreign investment and foreign peoples who otherwise might have avoided the historically ultra socially conservative state.